# Controlling and ignoring (revisiting this concept to make the difference clear)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

(I'm aware there are other related questions.) I'm struggling with the concept of "controlling" in a regression analysis where one variable is **binary (0,1)** and a **Professor of mine** said in our stats class that the term control or ignoring is not right:

> "It is not ignoring Group, it is taking the average outcome for the not-GROUP and Groups into account while weighting for the N size of each of the groups (which I didn’t mention in class)."

I think this sentence is not 100% correct but I want to figure out that. So, this question is: **what´s the math formula for the explain the difference between two predicted outcomes (one using a binary group + continuous) another using only the continuous.** All codes below could be load in R and i "attached" some figures to clarify this question.

Let's assume 10 students (5 with disability **(group=1)**, 5 control (group=0)) were tested in a math and writing test. Now, I have a dataset like the code below:

```
options(scipen = 999) # avoid scientific notation
library(dplyr)        # request library
set.seed(123)         # same numbers everytime
dataset <- data.frame(group = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)),
                      math = c(rnorm(5,8,1), rnorm(5,3,2)),
                      reading = c(rnorm(5,7,1), rnorm(5,4,2)))
dataset[] <-round(dataset[], 1)  # round numbers
```

I can regress the math score on group and writing (model 1) and I can also regress math score on writing (model 2) to see the difference between "controlling" and "ignoring".

```
# regression model full
mod <- lm(math ~ reading + group, data=dataset)
# display results
summary(mod)
# regression model only reading
mod2 <- lm(math ~ reading, data=dataset)
# display results
summary(mod2)
```

First model:

```
lm(formula = math ~ reading + group, data = dataset)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0430 -0.3655  0.1399  0.5040  1.3478 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   3.5242     1.6383   2.151   0.0685 .
reading       0.6405     0.2116   3.027   0.0192 *
group        -3.3400     1.0080  -3.314   0.0129 *
```

Second model:

```
lm(formula = math ~ reading, data = dataset)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5464 -0.8077 -0.0328  1.1261  2.2719 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  -0.7441     1.5176  -0.490  0.63706   
reading       1.0908     0.2431   4.487  0.00204 **
```

The last part of the syntax expresses the concept of "controlling", once it reports a predicted value for a model with a binary variable and a predicted value for a model without this binary variable:

```
# get means
descriptive <- dataset %>%
               group_by(group) %>%
               summarise_all(funs(mean(.),n()))
# insert predicted values for each model
dataset$math_full         <- predict(mod)
dataset$math_reading_only <- predict(mod2)
# get the difference between each prediction
dataset$difference <- abs(dataset$math_full - dataset$math_reading_only)
```

As we can see, there´s nothing new in this output. But, if the professor is right, the difference is computed by **taking the average outcome for the not-GROUP and Groups into account while weighting for the N size of each of the groups**, what I don´t think it's right.

[image: Model results]

The descriptive results, if someone want to do this calculation by hand (which I'd appreciate), are below:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  group math_mean reading_mean math_full_mean math_reading_only_mean difference_mean math_n
  <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>                  <dbl>           <dbl>  <int>
1     0       8.2         7.30            8.2               7.218976       0.9810243      5
2     1       2.9         4.24            2.9               3.881024       1.3343249      5
# ... with 4 more variables: reading_n <int>, math_full_n <int>, math_reading_only_n <int>,
#   difference_n <int>
```

The code here can be used in R.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't see a "?" anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I edited the text to make it clear. The question is related to math formula to achieve the difference (last figure) between two regression models. The first model y=b0+b1CONTINUOUS+b2BINARY and the second model is y=b0+b1CONTINUOUS. the difference between both predicted values will be useful to understand the concept of "controlling for". Thanks.